# How can I get the selected mode?

Tags: c#, edsdk

I need to get the selected mode of the [camera dial](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Canon_EOS_mode_dial.jpg) (Manual, Auto, Auto+, ...) but i can't find the right property. Does this property even exist ? If yes, what is it ?
The property that I'm looking for is in following image, the "P" in EOS Utility :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih3z0.jpg)

Your post on [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688276/Canon-EDSDK-Tutorial-in-Csharp) is very useful !

Thanks !

Comment: Hi there! Could you elaborate on your question? It seems out of context for me when you asked: "Your post on CodeProject is very useful !"

Comment: what are the values of selected mode? you mean `iso` , `av` and ...?

Comment: @Pankwood he is talking about my Canon EDSDK Tutorial on CodeProject. It is a very vague reference though if you don't know what this is about.

Comment: Good to hear from you. Please, could you add URL on your comment, or edit the question with it? Thx

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `PropertyID.AEMode`. AEMode stands for Auto Exposure Mode (even if it includes Manual).